# Intergrate an existing React template in Laravel project

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm developing a website using React with Laravel, I'm very beginner with React and I hope to integrate an existing template dashboard in laravel project.

The structure of react template:

```
 .
├── public                  # static files
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html          # main HTML file
│   ├── robots.txt
├── src                     # source files
│   ├── app                 # redux store
│   ├── assets              # static assets
│   ├── components          # reusable components shared across the app
│   ├── constants           
│   ├── contexts            # context providers
│   ├── db                  # fake database
│   ├── features            # redux features (slices)
│   ├── fonts               
│   ├── hooks               # custom hooks
│   ├── layout              # main layout components (header, sidebar, etc.)
│   ├── pages               
│   ├── styles              # global styles
│   ├── ui                  # reusable UI components
│   ├── utils               # helper functions
│   ├── widgets             # reusable widgets
│   ├── App.js              # main app component
│   ├── index.js            # app entry point
│   ├── layouts.js          # layout object for react-grid-layout
│   ├── style.scss          # global app styles
├── .htaccess                       # htaccess file for Apache server
├── babel-plugin-macros.config.js   # babel macros config (for styled-components)
├── craco.config.js                 # custom CRA config
├── jsconfig.json                   # jsconfig for IDE
├── package.json
```

I started by adding react with : `composer require laravel/ui`, then I copied all files in `resource/js` folder but here I'm stucking and I don't know how I can integrate it and displaying it in laravel view?

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you haven't generated the scaffolding of react within Laravel with this command: `php artisan ui react`

If you want registration scaffolding along with it use: `php artisan ui react --auth`